# Android GPS EXIF data returns null or empty, but device shows location

Tags: android, exif, android-gps

One of my users has a device that shows the location of a photo, but when we try to upload it, the tags are set to null or 0/0

It might be the browser?

We are trying to upload via a web app with a success rate of 99% of the time.

This is what we are seeing in the logs

```
    'GPSLatitudeRef' => NULL,
    'GPSLatitude' => 
    array (
      0 => '0/0',
      1 => '0/0',
      2 => '0/0',
    ),
    'GPSLongitudeRef' => NULL,
    'GPSLongitude' => 
    array (
      0 => '0/0',
      1 => '0/0',
      2 => '0/0',
    ),
    'GPSAltitudeRef' => '' . "\0" . '',
    'GPSAltitude' => '0/0',
    'GPSTimeStamp' => 
    array (
      0 => '0/0',
      1 => '0/0',
      2 => '0/0',
    ),
```

Why might these tags be removed, and what can we do about it?

Answer (score 1):

Tags are not removed during upload. An exif header is not removed during upload of a file. Well if you do the upload correctly. Are number of bytes of original and uploaded one equal?

On some devices the default Camera app puts an exif header in the produced jpg file. But the exif header does not contain lat,lon tags.

Instead the latitude and longitude are stored as meta data for the file in the mediastore.

Have a look there.